# php - How to match Japanese regular expression with u flag?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Something weird is happening with `preg_match` when I feed it the following strings. I am using the 'u' flag because I am trying to match a mixed Japanese string.

```
<?php
 $subject="/hello/カメラ/";
 $pattern='#^/hello/([\p{Han}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\w\-]+)/#u';
 $result=preg_match($pattern,$subject);
 echo $result; // 1

 $subject="/hello/カレンダー/";
 $pattern='#^/hello/([\p{Han}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\w\-]+)/#u';
 $result=preg_match($pattern,$subject);
 echo $result; // 0
?>
```

Notice that both $pattern variables have the same construction '/hello/katakana/'. Then, why is the first `$result` 1 and the second one 0?

Is that a bug?

Update:
I am running PHP Version 5.5.24 on a Mac.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running? I've just tested your code on my computer with version 5.5.9 and both results are 1.

Comment: Must be running an older version of PHP, https://3v4l.org/frX5U.

Comment: @DavidVartanian I am running PHP Version 5.5.24 on a Mac. So, this was a bug after all, huh

Comment: Yes possibly. Maybe this also helps: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#94424. Did you see it?

Comment: @DavidVartanian No. I just looked at it. I update the regexp for using ranges and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to David Vartanian for his help.

To make the regular expression work for both cases, I had to update the pattern the following way.

```
$pattern='#^/hello/([\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}\x{3040}-\x{309F}\x{4E00}-\x{9FBF}\w\-]+)/#u';
```

However, it seems like the older pattern works on PHP 5.5.9 and newer as mentioned by chris.

Comment: I suggest that you update your PHP. Newer version of PHP comes with numerous bug fixes and update to the libraries (in this case, the regex engine PCRE)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mb_ereg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-match.php), this function is especially for multibyte regex, do no confuse with `ereg_*` deprecated. To use it just remove the delimiters and the modifier `u`.

```
<?php

$subject="/hello/カメラ/";
$pattern='^/hello/([\p{Han}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\w\-]+)/';
$result =  mb_ereg_match($pattern, $subject);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);

$subject="/hello/カレンダー/";
$pattern='^/hello/([\p{Han}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\w\-]+)/';
$result =  mb_ereg_match($pattern, $subject);

print_r($result);
```